# HappyLager Demo Site Forcing 'https://' on XAMPP

Tags: config, installation, hosting

**When I try to load the demo site in my browser I get the following error:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU6Xm.jpg "Your connection is not secure"

**I have added the following to my hosts file:**

`127.0.0.7        happylager.dev`

**and this to my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/HappyLager/public/
    ServerName happylager.dev
    ServerAlias http://happylager.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

**Content of .htaccess files:**

**The `.htaccess` file in the public folder contains:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**The `.htaccess` file in the craft folder contains:**

`deny from all`

**XAMPP versioning information:**

- PHP Version 7.04
- phpMyAdmin version 4.5.1

This error occured during step 7 and 8 on this page:

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager

Rebooted as well just in case. When I try to resolve 'happylager.dev' or 'http://happylager.dev' the error still persists. The virtual hosts resolve other names without error. Any idea what I might not be considering? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is actually the use of the TLD .dev. Google now owns that extension and in Chrome (which later, other browsers including Safari and Firefox enforced) it now forces the URL to go over SSL. If you don’t want to deal with all that self-signed certificate stuff to get SSL working locally, your best bet is to just switch the extension to something like .test and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was being too cautious. I assumed that .dev was required by Craft. I made a pull request with an edit to the README.me. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Not at all. I think this is an issue people still come across and having this question and answer documented is valuable. If that did work for you be sure to mark it as the accepted answer.